# Images Not Visible After Deployment - 404 Error Next.js 13 - deployed thorough GitHub

Tags: image, github, web, next.js, next.js13

Description:
I am facing an issue with my Next.js website where all the images are not visible after deployment. The website works perfectly fine when running locally using npm run dev and even after building the project with npm run build. However, after deploying the website, all the images result in a 404 error from the server, and they do not load on the live site.

Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified Image Paths: I have double-checked the paths of the image URLs, and they seem to be correct. The images are located in the public folder, and the paths are relative to this folder.

Checked Image Formats: I am using common image formats such as PNG and JPG, which are supported by the next-images plugin in my next.config.js file.

Configured Image Domains: To ensure that images from external domains are accessible, I have added the relevant domains to the images configuration in next.config.js.

Verified Image Imports: I have carefully checked how I am importing the images in my components to ensure that the image sources are correct.

Cleared Cached Assets: To rule out any caching issues, I have cleared the browser cache multiple times.

Checked Deployment Process: I have followed the correct deployment process, and all the image files are included in the deployment.

Despite taking these steps, I am still encountering the issue of images not being visible after deployment, resulting in a 404 error from the server.

```
next.config.js : 

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const withFonts = require('next-fonts');
const withImages = require('next-images'); // Import next-images plugin

const nextConfig = {
experimental: {
    appDir: true,
},
// Add the images configuration for image formats
// This will support PNG, JPG, JPEG, GIF, and SVG formats
images: {
    domains: [], // Add any domains if you are using external image URLs
},
 output: 'export',
};

module.exports = withFonts(withImages(nextConfig)); // Add withImages to the chain
```

github repo:  https://github.com/ElonAbergel/Etagrili

The website: https://etgarili.com/

Comment: same issue mate. how did you fix it?